# Image resizer has stopped working

Tags: windows-10

I love this tool, it's simple effectiveness and have been using it for while. But when I try using it now I get an error message "Can't resize the following pictures , pier.jpg, could not find file c:users/jon/pier (large).jpg. This assumes I was asking for a large file, or I get phone for a phone sized one. The weird thing is it is giving this message before creating the new file. I also get the message if I ask it to resize the original picture and not make copies. Any help appreciated

Comment: This one? https://www.bricelam.net/ImageResizer/ Or the one on the Microsoft Store?

Comment: FWIW, I've been using the bricelam powertoy clone for years with no problems. If you're using something else, you may want to try switching to it. Or, if you're already using it, perhaps a simple reinstall will solve your problem.

Comment: powertoy clone is no longer available for download on the site.>>>>>https://www.bricelam.net/2009/04/image-resizer-powertoy-clone-for.html